# Stage.RESIZE : Is it possible to run this example in a browser?

Tags: actionscript-3, browser, resize, local

Is it possible to run this simple code in a browser?
In the .swf all seems to work fine, but I'm unable to resize the .swf in a browser...
The stage is not resizing in an HTML page.
Through the .swf flile it works like a charm.
Do somebody have an idea about this issue?

```
package com{
    import flash.display.Graphics;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageQuality;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.text.TextField;

public class Main extends MovieClip{
    private static const ORANGE:int = 0xff9900;
    var bg:MovieClip;
    var bg_mask:MovieClip;
    var marginx:int = 10;
    var marginy:int = 10;
    var display:MovieClip;
    var displayTextField:TextField;
    var ellipseWidth:int = 90;
    var ellipseHeight:int = 90;
    public function Main(){
        super();
        bg = new MovieClip();
        bg_mask = new MovieClip();
        display = new MovieClip();
        displayTextField = new TextField();
        this.addChild(bg);
        this.addChild(bg_mask);
        this.addChild(display);
        this.display.addChild(displayTextField);
        displayTextField.text = "";
        displayTextField.x = ellipseWidth/Math.PI;
        displayTextField.y = ellipseHeight/Math.PI;
        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;  // or StageAlign.TOP
        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
        drawBackground();
        display.mask = bg_mask;
        addListeners();
    }
    private function drawBackground(thickness:int=1,lineColor:int=0x000000,lineAlpha:Number=0.5,fillColor:int=ORANGE,fillAlpha:Number=0.5):void{
        var g:Graphics = bg.graphics;
        g.clear();
        g.lineStyle(thickness,lineColor,lineAlpha);
        g.beginFill(fillColor,fillAlpha);
        g.drawRoundRect(marginx,marginy,this.stage.stageWidth-marginx*2,this.stage.stageHeight-marginy*2,ellipseWidth,ellipseHeight);
        g.endFill();
    }
    private function drawMask():void{
        var g:Graphics = bg_mask.graphics;
        g.clear();
        g.lineStyle(1,0x000000,0.3);
        g.beginFill(0xcccccc,0.1);
        g.drawRoundRect(marginx,marginy,this.stage.stageWidth-marginx*2,this.stage.stageHeight-marginy*2,90,90);
        g.endFill();
    }
    private function addListeners():void{
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ADDED,updateLabel);
        stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE,updateLabel);
    }
    private function updateLabel(e:Event):void{
        updateDisplay();
        drawBackground();
        drawMask();
    }
    private function updateDisplay():void{
        var tf:TextField = displayTextField;
        tf.text = ("{" + this.stage.stageWidth + ";" + this.stage.stageHeight + "}");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You'll need to show the HTML markup that places the swf in the html page.   That is likely where you issue lies.  If it's using fixed sizing then it doesn't matter what you've done in your AS3 code.

Comment: Why didn't you post this as an answer and not as a comment (I'm not able to accept your answer as the correct one in this case)?
It's working perfectly!
Thank you a lot.
Since I set the  stage.scaleMode as :
    stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
I thought it was overriding my Html css...
Stupid mistake!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an online context, the flash document is contained within an HTML parent element (object/embed).

Your AS3 code controls how to display your flash content within that element.  It does not know anything beyond it's container.

Most likely, your issue is that HTML container.  If it has a fixed size, then no matter what you do in AS3 it will not scale beyond it's container.

Try giving your HTML container fluid dimensions (eg. 100% width, 100% height) as well as any grandparent html elements to make your sizing more dynamic.